# Python convenient passing of dictionary arguments to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, scope

I thought about attaching the dictionary to the local scope somehow, however I have seen similar questions asked on SO - usually with the response 'don't do it!'. I will illustrate my problem and welcome any suggestions to overcome this.

If have an options dictionary (read from JSON so prefer not to have to mess to much with it) and I have decided to pass this as follows;

```
def testParse(dataObj, userOptions):

    # Merge default with passed options taking prescidence
    defaultOpts = {

        'boxheight' : 200,
        'boxwidth'  : 100,
        'padding'   : 150

    }
    opt = dict(userOptions.items() | defaultOpts.items())
```

The question is; Is there any way to attach each value in the dictionary to the local scope using the key so that rather than copying out the entire dictionary

```
boxheight = opt['boxheight']
```

etc., or writing `opt['boxheight']` every time I refer to it. Can I just loop the `opt` dictionary and assign the value programatically?

I am in no way attached to the approach outlined, but all options will be used in local expressions at some point and they exist from the outset as a dictionary. Many thanks in advance for your suggestions.

[Disclaimer: Only been working with Python for a few days]

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do this for local variables.  How many items are there in the dicitonary?  I suggest explicit assignments.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with this is have keyword arguments to sub-functions, then just unpack the dictionary into the call (e.g. `def func(padding, **kwargs)` then `func(**opt)` will make `padding` locally available in `func` and pack everything else into `kwargs`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - beautiful!

Comment: Another option is to use a namespace object `class Namespace: pass`.  This can be used as `opt = Namepsace(); vars(opt).update(defaultOptions); vars(opt).update(userOptions)`.  After that, you can access the opts as `opt.boxheight`, which you might find a less noisy syntax.

Comment: @ Sven Marnach - like this also! Thanks

Comment: As a side node, your way of constructing the merged dictionary results in an arbitrary value being chosen in case a key appears in both `userOptions` and `defaultOpts`.

Comment: @Sven any thoughts on the answer I have posted - are there any other benefits / shortcomings of your solutions

Comment: @jonrsharpe same goes - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @jonrshapre's comment I have the following solution

```
# user options
userOps = { 'name' : 'joe', 'age' : 21 }
data = (1,2)

# default options specified as function argument
def _func(data, name, lovesSO = True, **kwargs):

    print(data)
    print(name)
    print(lovesSO)
    print(kwargs)

# Call
_func(data, **userOps)    

# OUTPUTS
# (1,2)
# joe
# True
# {'age' : 21}
```

The price to pay with this approach appears to be the slightly unconventional calling syntax (although as pointed out in the comments this is only unusual to a newbee like me). However this can be fixed up by defining

```
def func(data, options): _func(data, **options)
```

Or another solution based upon @ Sven Marnach's comment;

```
# Utility options class
class Options:
    def __init__(self, defaults, user_opts):
        vars(self).update(defaults)
        vars(self).update(user_opts)

def func2(data, userOps):

    opt = Options({ 'lovesSO' : True}, userOps)

    print(data)
    print(opt.name)
    print(opt.lovesSO)

# Call    
func2(data, userOps)

# OUTPUT
# (1, 2)
# joe
# True
```

This has the drawback of defining a helper class but has the benefit of clearly knowing which variables are user definable options by the presence of the `opt.` prefix. In addition the calling syntax is natural.

In both cases, unused user options are stored as either the `kwargs` dictionary (in the first case) or as unused entries in the `opt` dictionary.

Personally I have decided to opt for the second solution.

Comment: *"slightly unconventional calling syntax"* seems inaccurate - `*` and `**` are widely used in idiomatic Python. Note also that these would be used in different ways - with Sven's, you would pass a single `Namespace` object **to** `func2`, containing all the user options, rather than creating the `Namespace` *inside* the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Re: Sven's approach; If I define the Namespace object outside func2 then the default options would overwrite the user options no? It would seem that then I would need to do some sort of key checking?

Comment: I would suggest defining the `Namespace` class at the global level, and giving it a constructor accepting the defaults and user options.  This way, the boilerplate inside the function will basically disappear.

Comment: You *wouldn't* update the `Namespace` inside `func2` - if you have local defaults to use in case an attribute is missing, you'd do e.g. `lovesSO = getattr(opts, "lovesSO", True)`. Note you can also use `setattr` to update the namespace if you only have one value to set - `setattr(opts, "lovesSO", True)`.

Comment: @Sven Marnach - any better? Sorry for the back and forth - still learning!